# Creating a symbolic link to a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, symbolic-link

I have a directory to which I want to create a symbolic link. The commands I used were:

```
cd workspace_b4a
cd android-sdk-linux
ln -sv build-tools/20.0.0/lib/ platform-tools/lib
```

The output was:

```
‘platform-tools/lib’ -> ‘build-tools/20.0.0/lib/’
```

However, Nautilus says that `platform-tools/lib` is a broken link and `ls -l platform-tools/lib` shows the both `build-tools/20.0.0/lib/` and `platform-tools/lib` in red. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -la platform-tools/lib | grep "^l"`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/create-a-symbolic-link-relative-to-the-current-directory).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I found it easiest to understand how to do it (though I still don't understand the logic behind it) with:

```
cd ~/workspace_b4a
cd android-sdk-linux
cd platform-tools
ln -sv ../build-tools/20.0.0/lib/ .
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are in directory `/path/to/common/root`:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/common/root
```

which has a subdirectory `build-tools/20.0.0/lib`:

```
$ readlink -e build-tools/20.0.0/lib
/path/to/common/root/build-tools/20.0.0/lib
```

and subdirectory `platform-tools`, but no file or directory `platform-tools/lib`:

```
$ ls -d platform-tools
platform-tools
$ ls platform-tools/lib
ls: cannot access platform-tools/lib: No such file or directory
```

and you want to make `platform-tools/lib` a symlink to `build-tools/20.0.0/lib`, then you can either make it an **absolute link**:

```
$ ln -s /path/to/common/root/build-tools/20.0.0/lib platform-tools/lib
$ ls -l platform-tools/lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 72 Sep 16 12:57 platform-tools/lib -> /path/to/common/root/build-tools/20.0.0/lib
$ readlink -e platform-tools/lib
/path/to/common/root/build-tools/20.0.0/lib
```

or you can make it a **relative link**:

```
$ ln -s ../build-tools/20.0.0/lib platform-tools/lib
$ ls -l platform-tools/lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 25 Sep 16 12:58 platform-tools/lib -> ../build-tools/20.0.0/lib
$ readlink -e platform-tools/lib
/path/to/common/root/build-tools/20.0.0/lib
```

while noting that the relative link must be *relative to the symlink file itself*, not to the location where you run the `ln -s` command. To make sure you don't get that wrong (and because you get convenient tab completion with it), there are two options:

Either go to the symlink's directory first, and create the symlink there:

```
$ cd platform-tools  
$ ln -s ../build-tools/20.0.0/lib lib  # The last lib is optional
```

Or use the `-r` option to make `ln` figure out the relative path while you specify paths relative to your current directory:

```
$ ln -sr build-tools/20.0.0/lib platform-tools/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

You can link to a non existing PATH (either file or directory)

```
abox $ ls
abox $ ln -s foo bar
abox $ ls
bar  (<- in red)
abox $ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 archemar archemar 3 sept. 16 10:47 bar -> foo  ## both foo and bar in red
```

Why someone would do that ?

Latter, i can create foo file/dir, and link will work.

while  directory `build-tools/20.0.0/lib/` does not exsists, your link will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that you are in a directory

> /media/john/android/workspace_b4a/android-sdk-linux/

and you want to create a symbolic link for '/build-tools/20.0.0/lib' dir  it. You can do that by

```
     ln -sv /media/john/android/workspace_b4a/android-sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/lib platform-tools/lib
```

**EDIT** : The output of

```
   ls -l platform-tools/lib
```

Will also be changed.

Comment: you can link with relative pathname.

Comment: My apologies for misguidance.