# Creating the $LFS tools Directory

Tags: 14.04, symbolic-link

i am working on [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/creatingtoolsdir.html), and getting this error creating symbolic links. i checked this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524606/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-a-directory) but no help, also googled but nothing works.

```
# ln -sv $LFS/tools /
‘/tools’ -> ‘/mnt/lfs/tools’
```

in root directory, i see a file *tools*, with link symbol on it. double clicking throws an error *"the link cannot be used because its target /mnt/tools does not exist"*

also checked env variable

```
# echo $LFS
/mnt/lfs
```

any help would be awesome.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, i've figured it out.

i had previously mounted partition

```
mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sda4 $LFS
```

for some reason, this mount was not working anymore, probably after restart. i found it when i checked directory */mnt/lfs*  - it was empty, all the folders that i had created were in partition *sda4* which i had previously mounted.

re-mounted partition,

```
#ln -sv $LFS/tools /
```

and it works now.

2nd question: what happened to mount, why does it stop working after restart ? at the same time, environment variable $LFS also resets ?

Answer (score 0):

```
what happened to mount, why does it stop working after restart ? at the same time, environment variable $LFS also resets ?
```

If its not in fstab, it wont be mounted upon restart. So add the drive to fstab if you like it to be mounted upon restart.

the latest LFS manual definitly states this in a warning aswell [2.7. Mounting the New Partition - Linux From Scratch - Version 11.2](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/11.2/chapter02/mounting.html)